# AWS Api Gateway Custom Trigger or Interceptor that gets called for every Request while using Cognito Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito-triggers

I have an AWS API Gateway which has many end points all of which are Authorized through a Cognito based Authorizer. So the Cognito is generating all the JWT tokens for me and I am using this Cognito Authorizer to Authenticate my end points.

I need a way where I want a Lambda to be acting as an Interceptor for each and every request(at least all the ones that are invoked post login by the user) to allow/deny the requests before it further processes the Lambdas which are proxied to(invoked to) the API Gateway.

I tried the triggers given by Cognito and that did not work to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a CloudFront distribution in front of an API Gateway and associate CloudFront distribution with a Lambda@Edge function. CloudFront intercepts requests and responses at CloudFront edge locations.

[Customizing at the edge with Lambda@Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html)